# CellList in GWT, can't clear it

Tags: java, gwt

I can't clear CellList in GWT, i have done some research and found a post where some guy explain that using replaceAllChildren() but there is no method in CellList class. I m with GWT 2.3 .
Actually this method present in class AbstractHasData which is extended from CellList class but unavailable.

Any ideas how can i clear it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `cellList.setRowCount(0)` ?