# DataGrid in GWT, can't clear it

Tags: java, gwt, datagrid

I am populating a DataGrid in GWT on a button click. It is working fine but if I try to re-populate it, the **data gets appended** to the existing table.

I am using **UI Binder/GWT 2.5** to create DataGrid.

I have already tried this:

```
    // My list which gets updated with the response of RPC. Initially it is empty.
    List<List<String>> tableRowData = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
    grid.setRowCount(0); // Clears all data.
    grid.setRowCount(tableRowData.size(), true); // Set the size of the new data.
    grid.setRowData(0, tableRowData); // Set the new data.

    Populate tableRowData...

    Populate data grid // works perfect
```

Also since GWT 2.1.1, there is a new method setRowData(List)

Each element of the list tableRowData is again a list of strings. Is it even possible **without
using ListDataProvider**. For first time it works perfect, though.
Can anyone please point out what I am missing.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9380202/gwt-celltable-columnsorting/9389172#9389172. I did not use dataprovider. Simply grabbed hold of the list for the celltable and manipulated it.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - Good post. Any chance you can share your code so that people don't have to "take the table list by its bull-horns" themselves?

Comment: I left my code with my old project and I would have to meditate a lil' bit to get it back. But what I did was embarrassingly simple. I think I did use setRowData. What is missing here is probably setRowCount-exact to zero, every time you need to replace the list, and then setRowCount-exact to the size of the new list.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to manage `Cell` widgets is using a `DataProvider`. GWT's showcase has some [elaborate examples](http://gwt.google.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwCellList), but you should be fine with a simple `ListDataProvider` as long as your list is guaranteed to be small.

```
ListDataProvider<List<String>> dataProvider = new ListDataProvider<List<String>>();
dataProvider.addDisplay(dataGrid);

List<List<String>> newData = ...;
dataProvider.getList().clear();
dataProvider.getList().addAll(newData);
```

For more information, check out the new [GWT documentation about data providers](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiCellWidgets#data-provider). Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9455506/151365) for tweaks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply logan. But I am not using ListDataProvider. Is it possible to achieve what I need without using ListDataProvider?

Comment: It is possible, but you would basically just be rebuilding ListDataProvider. Just look through the source of ListDataProvider

Comment: @mohit after looking through the source for a bit, I can't find the error in your ways. I had a similar problem recently (a celllist didn't remove empty values), and the way I fixed it was by using a ListDataProvider

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6443043/768894 , they are doing it without any DataProvider.

Comment: @mohit - It is entirely possible to not use a DataProvider. Internally they call just call `grid.setRowData`... it's just code that's tested to work nicely with all the SelectionEvents, ScheduleFinally and pendingState behind the scenes. What's the downside to using a ListDataProvider?

Comment: "Internally they call just call grid.setRowData" then why it is not working when I am calling it explicitly. At the begining of my method I am creating an empty list and calling setRowData() with this blank list later in the method I populate this list and again call setRowData which works fine.

Comment: I do recall now - I had simply studied ListDataProvider and created a simple list manager/updater.